# What is the source for the tying of Breslov Tzitzis?

Tags: sources-mekorot, tzitzis, breslov

I recently saw a tzitzis tying method I had never seen before - apparently, according to Ben's Tallit Shop, this method is one of the various methods of Breslov tzitzis tying. I understand Breslov generally uses the Arizal/Chabad method for their tzitzis, but where did this method come from? Did Rabbi Nachman or some other Breslover rabbi invent it? It appears to be some sort of combination between Rambam and Arizal tzitzis. (Notice the chulyos with the inclusion of the 5 knots, as well as the half-string techeiles.) Could someone offer an explanation or source on where this method came from? I have included some pictures for easy access. The first 2 are Breslov (one with techeiles the other not) and the 3rd one is one of the Yemenite methods, which is very similar, minus the 5 knots. (Look in comments for the Yemenite picture)

[image: Picture 1]

[image: Picture 2]

**Edit:** The photos are from Ben's Tallit Shop.

Comment: can you perhaps describe the breslov method of tzitizis tying? Pictures would be even better

Comment: @ezra That looks just like the Yemenite method of tying Sisith. Where did you hear that those are Breslov Tzitzit?

Comment: @DoubleAA - They are not Yemenite/Rambam tzitzit. Yemenite tzitzit do not include the five double knots. But yes, the way the chulyot are structured are almost the same, with the exception that some of the winds in Breslov tzitzit have two or one windings, rather than three every time, to make the number of winds 7-8-11-13, like  Ashkenazi/Arizal tzitzit.

Comment: @DoubleAA - Here is a picture of what Yemenite tzitzit look like: http://www.tallit-shop.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/IMG_4438_1.jpg

Comment: Regarding the two photos of the Breslav tie, they appear to follow a variation of the tie from the Ari z"l. The chuliyot (the 3 wind clusters) are 7, 8, 11, and 13. If not using techelet, it appears fine. I am surprised with what the techelet example is. The strings are according to Rambam. The blue is only a half string. To my knowledge, the Ari would follow Ra'avad practice of a full blue thread. Also, the Ari says that the chuliyot are to alternate, starting with white, then blue, white, etc. The Yemenite photo appears to follow the custom from the Gaonim as stated by the Ra'avad.

Comment: @YaacovDeane - I don't know about sources from the Ari HaKodesh himself, but it seems most everyone who ties according to the Arizal/Chabad method with techeiles uses a half-blue string. (There is custom of tying Arizal tzitzis with a full blue string, but it is not very established.) Maybe you could add some sources to educate me, please, regarding the alternating chulyos? As for the Yemenite tzitzith, I just pulled it off Google so don't blame if it follows a certain method or not, I am not very well versed in Temani minhagim. :)

Comment: @EzraHoerster For an excellent and quite thorough discussion of the subject this link is what you are looking for. http://tekhelet.com/tekhelet-tying-faq/

Comment: @YaacovDeane - How does this link help? I know about Arizal and Rambam methods. I want to know about the BRESLOV METHOD, as I posted pictures above. The method I showed pictures of above have no entry in the link you attached.

Comment: In general, Rambam's view of a half thread is 'odd man out'. There is no clear instruction about this because real techelet use is relatively recent. A klal in regard to mitzvah observance is that they are 'full' or 'whole'. So the idea of using a half died thread is unusual. However, it could be that it somehow relates to the concept of the 'Chatzotzrot', 'trumpets'. That develops the idea of 'chatzi-tzurot', half forms which comprise a whole. The same concept applies to the half shekel given for the census and also that Moshe was 'Ish-Elokim', literally 'Man-G-d'.

Comment: Breslav appears to follow Ari z"l.

Comment: @YaacovDeane - yes most times but what about THIS METHOD.

Comment: The tie is Ari z"l.

Comment: @YaacovDeane - I am sorry but maybe you could explain? Arizal tying does not look like this. It looks like this: http://cdn1.bigcommerce.com/server4800/78164/product_images/uploaded_images/chabad-techeles.jpg

Comment: Whoever tied in the photos simply spaced out the chuliyot evenly in the spaces between the double knots. Most likely to be exacting in the idea that the space between each of the double knots is supposed to be one thumbs width. But the tie is definitely Ari z"l.

Comment: @EzraHoerster Both photos, the Ben's Tallit Shop and your second photo of the Ari tie with techelet are identical in style. I will point out that both versions are not including the alternating chuliyot colors which are also required. First chuliya must be the same color as the beged, meaning white. Next chuliyah is techelet, etc. That makes 13 total chuliyot, 6 of one color and 7 of the other. The 7 correspond to the 7 heavens.

Comment: Are these photos yours? If not, do you have permission from their owners to republish them? If not, you should not use Mi Yodeya to do so. In any case, please caption them, attributing them to their sources.

Comment: Thanks to you I begin to learn the matter of Tsitsit. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

If I am not mistaken, the Breslovers tie  their tzitizis using a triple loop. Similar to sfardi, but the sfardi method is a loop on every winding of the shammes string whereas the Breslovers method is every third.

This method was not made up by R' Nachman, it was made up by the Arizal. (At least that's how the Ba'al haTanya understood it). The Breslovers are actually not the only ones who tie their tzitzis like this. Chabad and many other Chassidim do too. Breslov is unique in the fact that they have tcheiles strings also, as opposed to the other factions.
Here is a picture of Chabad Tzitzis:

[image: chabad tzitzis]

And here is sfardi tzitzis:

[image: sfardi]

You have to look closely, but you can see the difference between the two versions.

Belz also has a loop every third winding, but its a bit different. The way they understand the Arizal, is that the Shamess string (the long one that is used to circle the others) should go THROUGH the other 7 strings on every third winding. They are also careful to keep the two sets of strings separate through every loop. (Meaning, at the beginning, there are 4 strings that are folded over to make 8. They are careful that the split that the shammes makes should have the same 4 strings on each side every time).

Comment: I have seen Breslov tzitzit; they're tied like the Rambam, but with double knots to make the sections add up to 7-8-11-13.

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt - I have seen that too. That was the method I was trying to ask about. I already knew about the Arizal method (Thank you anyway Mennyg). Here's a picture of it: https://www.google.com/search?q=Breslov+Tzitzit+Tying&espv=2&biw=1280&bih=923&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjVvdKGqLLOAhUGw2MKHaKaD60Q_AUIBygC#imgrc=ZwZpK493NHW0LM%3A (Thanks Ben's Tallit Shop)

Comment: @EzraHoerster, that's exactly what I was thinking of. I was looking for a Breslover website to link an image, but I couldn't find it. They probably rely on the same makor as Chabad though.

Comment: Its the same as chabad but inside out. Look closely, you'll see the strings looping inside

Comment: @EzraHoerster, one moral may be: Ask a clearer question from the outset.