# Whose opinion / custom for tying tzitzit is this?

Tags: sources-mekorot, minhag, tzitzis

I recently saw a hassidic gentleman in *shul*, with *tzitzit* tied in a way I had never seen before. Unfortunately, I did not get a chance to speak to him, and I was wondering which opinion / custom he was following.

The *tzitzit* were all white (no *techelet*), and were tied with the regular *ashkenazi* five double knots.

However, in between the double knots there were individual groups of 3 wraps. There were two groups between the first two knots, three between knots 2 and 3, and then 4 between knots 3 and 4 and between knots 4 and 5, for a grand total of 13 groups.

So it looked something like:

--XX--lll--lll--XX--lll--lll--lll--XX--lll--lll--lll--lll--XX--lll--lll--lll--lll--XX-------

where XX is a double knot, lll is a group of three wraps, and -- are the strings without the wraps.

It seems similar to the Breslov method (described [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/75236/what-is-the-source-for-the-tying-of-breslov-tzitzis)) but without ensuring the 7-8-11-13 configuration as the Breslov method does.

Please provide sources for where this tying arrangement is described.

Comment: This is just standard Rambam with the addition of 5 double knots. Maybe a Yemenite guy who got into Chassidus? Without the double knots it would be completely normal on a Yemenite.

Comment: I'm having trouble picturing this. Or maybe I'm not, but if it's the way I'm picturing it then the groups between one knot and the next will collapse into one group very quickly.

Comment: @msh210 Similar to Yemenite tying, I imagine (althought I didn't see) that there are loops keeping the groups of three together. See the video  [here](http://www.tallit-shop.com/yemenite-tzitzit/)

Comment: @DoubleAA Agreed. I'm just wondering if there is a source for this combination of Rambam with the Sifrei's 5 knots...

Comment: @DoubleAA It's Breslov.